# LowPower library: Powerdown (sleep) an ATMega32u4 works but wakeup doesn't happen

Tags: c++, arduino, avr, wakeup, sleep-mode

**Situation:**

I made/developing this controller (with many functions) with use of a Pro Micro (ATMega32u4) and want to extend it with a wake-up functionality when touching it (with use of a touch sensor). This all to save some energy when not used. So when the device is picked up/touched, the device woke up. When there is no contact, it will go to sleep after a while. The reach distance of the touch sensor will be extended with a small strip of copper around the case.

**Picture of the device:**

[image: Image of device]

I use pin 9 of the touch sensor and the pin 16 of the IR-sensor to wake up but it doesn't work. Both device functions works OK, I can read the touch state (low=untouched or high=touched) and I can receive IR-commands because it is already fully implemented. When receiving a signal, those pins will be high for some period.

**Software question:**

Is there something wrong with my code (wrong parameters?)? The device goes to sleep when executing this code (but never woke up):

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>         // To enter sleep mode, save power
#include <LowPower.h>          // To enter sleep mode, save power 

......

#define TEP_IR_RECV_PIN         16
#define TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR     9

......
......

void sleep()
{
  attachInterrupt( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR, wakeup, HIGH );
  attachInterrupt( TEP_IR_RECV_PIN, wakeup, HIGH ); 

  // Enter power down state with ADC and BOD module disabled.
  // Wake up when wake up pin is high.
  LowPower.powerDown( SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF );

  // Disable external pin interrupt on wake up pin.
  detachInterrupt( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR );
  detachInterrupt( TEP_IR_RECV_PIN ); 
}
```

Sleep function of my EnjoyPad class (will be triggered when pushing power button on remote control or when reach timeout when not touched or doing anything):

```
void TEnjoyPad::setSleepMode()
{
  // Notify user device entering sleep mode, beep twice
  setBeep( 200 );
  setBeep( 200, 100, false );

  // To be sure: Trigger end / unhandled down events and reset states
  reset(init);

  // Handle sleep event
  eventSleep();

  // Stop all peripherals
  end();

  // Finally go to sleep, code stops here
  TEP_LIB_FUNCS::sleep();

  // Device woke up
  setBeep( 500, 100, false );

  // Restart all peripherals
  begin();

  // Handle wake up event
  eventAwake();
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? If I need to change a pin for the touch sensor, it is possible but I want to be sure it is the correct pin because I need to solder it (not on a breadboard). Pins left: 10, 14 and A3

*NOTICE: I have tested, with just a delay replacement instead of going to sleep, the functions after the sleep are working just fine. So I can hear a beep and device comes on again. There is no problem with the code after sleep(), it just doesn't want to wake-up.*

Comment: 328U4? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: You are right, changed the MCU typename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. It seems that pin 9 and pin 16 are not usable with attachInterrupt() so it will never work. Also the usage was not correct, it must be something like this:

```
attachInterrupt( digitalPinToInterrupt( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR ), wakeup, HIGH );
```

---

Came up with the idea to use a pin change interrupt to wake up the device and this seems to work. However, recovering from sleep mode cannot restore all peripherals without malfunctioning so it needs a hardware reset, it must start from scratch. Also because of changes when sleeping, for example cable disconnected from computer (it also has a battery) and USB connection is lost. Not all of the classes I use are mine and not optimized for such powerdown things.

Anyway, I change the code to this, just to show you the changes, maybe it can help others too:

---

```
#include <LowPower.h>          // To enter sleep mode, save power 
#include <avr/wdt.h>           // For watchDog device reset


......

#define TEP_IR_RECV_PIN         16
#define TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR     9

    ......
    ......

namespace TEP_LIB_FUNCS
{

void pciSetup(uint8_t iPin)
{
    *digitalPinToPCMSK( iPin ) |= bit( digitalPinToPCMSKbit( iPin ) );  // enable pin
    PCIFR|= bit( digitalPinToPCICRbit( iPin )); // clear any outstanding interrupt
    PCICR|= bit( digitalPinToPCICRbit( iPin )); // enable interrupt for the group
}

#if defined( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR )
 #if TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR >= 8 && TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR <= 13 
 ISR(PCINT0_vect) 
 {    
  #define TEP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_PIN_ENABLED 0 
  // Event handler for pins: D8 to D13 
  // Pin change wakeup event handler, does nothing but is required. 
  // Do not remove this.
 } 
 #elif defined(A0) && defined(A5) && TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR >= A0 && TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR <= A5 
 ISR(PCINT1_vect) 
 {    
  #define TEP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_PIN_ENABLED 1 
  // Event handler for pins: A0 to A5 
  // Pin change wakeup event handler, does nothing but is required. 
  // Do not remove this.
 } 
 #elif TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR >= 0 && TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR <= 7 
 ISR(PCINT2_vect) 
 {    
  #define TEP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_PIN_ENABLED 0 
  // Event handler for pins: A0 to A5 
  // Pin change wakeup event handler, does nothing but is required. 
  // Do not remove this.
 } 
 #endif
#endif

void sleep()
{
  // Possible pins Micro, Leonardo, other 32u4-based:  0, 1, 2, 3, 7.
  // Because we use all pins already by other functions, we cannot
  // use attachInterrupt(), it doesn't work.
  // see also: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt
  // Instead of this we use a change event interrupt to wake up 
  // the device from sleep state.  
  //
  // The device can be woke up by using:
  // - The reset button
  // - The touch sensor

  // Okay, lets go
  // We enable interrupts here to be sure it is going to work
 interrupts();

 #ifdef TEP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_PIN_ENABLED
  // Set pin change interrupt enabled for sensor pin
  // (See also https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PinChangeInterrupt)
   // old code: attachInterrupt( digitalPinToInterrupt( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR ), wakeup, HIGH );
   // old code: attachInterrupt( digitalPinToInterrupt( TEP_IR_RECV_PIN ), wakeup, HIGH ); 
  pciSetup( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR );
 #endif

 // Enter power down state with ADC and BOD module disabled.
 // Wake up when wake up pin has changed.
 LowPower.powerDown( SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF );

 // Disable external pin interrupt on wake up pin.
  // old code: detachInterrupt( TEP_PIN_TOUCHSENSOR );
  // old code: detachInterrupt( TEP_IR_RECV_PIN ); 
}


 void softReset()
 {
   wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS);  
   while(true) {}
 } 

  // Function Implementation
 void init(void)
 {
   MCUSR = 0;
   wdt_disable();
 }

} // end namespace TEP_LIB_FUNCS
```

---

And also the sleep function of my EnjoyPad class (will be triggered when pushing power button on remote control or when reach timeout when not touched or doing anything):

```
void TEnjoyPad::setSleepMode()
{
  // Notify user device entering sleep mode, beep twice
 setBeep( 200 );
 setBeep( 200, 100, false );

  // To be sure: Trigger end / unhandled down events and reset states
 reset(init);

  // Shut down any 
 broadcastSleepMode();

  // Handle sleep event
 eventSleep();

  // Stop all peripherals
 end();

  // Turn off onboard led
 digitalWrite( 13, LOW );
 pinMode( 13, INPUT ); 

  // Finally go to sleep, code stops here
 TEP_LIB_FUNCS::sleep();

  // Device woke up
 setBeep( 500, 100, false );

  // Handle wake up event
 eventAwake();

  // Restart whole device, start from scratch.
  // This seems to be the best way to guarantee all 
  // peripherals will be initialized properly
  // and without errors.
 TEP_LIB_FUNCS::softReset();
}
```

---

*NOTICE: Restarting this type of MCU is fast, there is no remarkable difference in speed when you wake up and continue or wake up and reset.*

That's it for the moment, tanks for watching ;-)

### ----------

EDIT: When adding `pciSetup( TEP_IR_RECV_PIN );` it also seems to work perfectly (because there is already an interrupt handler defined for it). So the device can also woke up when receiving an IR-command. Didn't expect this was possible but tried it, neat feature.